# Cronjob module not finish running

Tags: magento2, module, cron, crontab

I made a module to check if there are orders placed and if so then export them via another class. I can see the task getting created in the cron_schedule table however only the first one starts running and it keeps running, not finishing.

In this module I also have a controller file and if I go the the controller path the function executes so there's nothing wrong with the function I guess.

etc/crontab.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Cron:etc/crontab.xsd">
    <group id="default"> 
        <job name="order_export" instance="Vendor\Test\Cron\OrderExport" method="execute">
            <schedule>* * * * *</schedule>
        </job>
    </group>
</config>
```

Crontab works, cron jobs are created in cron_schedule table.

Cron/OrderExport.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Test\Cron;

use Vendor\Test\Helper\GrippApi;
use Vendor\Test\Helper\GrippExport;

class OrderExport 
{
    protected $_logger;

    protected $_orderCollectionFactory;

    protected $_orderRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\CollectionFactory $orderCollectionFactory
    ) {
        $this->_orderCollectionFactory = $orderCollectionFactory;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
        parent::__construct($context);

    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_logger->debug('Running Cron from Gripp OrderExport class');
        $today = date("Y-m-d");
        $orders = $this->_orderCollectionFactory
            ->create()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('created_at', array('gteq' => $today))
            ->addFieldToFilter('export_to_gripp', array('eq' => '0'))
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', array(
                array('eq' => 'pending'),
                array('eq' => 'processing')
            ));

        // Initialisatie API connector
        $apikey         = 'apikey';     
        $url            = 'url';  
        $api            = new GrippApi($apikey, $url);                  

        // Bepaal Betaalstatus
        $betaalstatus = 64;        

        foreach ($orders as $order){  
            $orderId = $order->getEntityId();

            $export = new GrippExport();
            $export->_api            = $api;
            $export->_order          = $order;
            $export->_betaalstatus   = $betaalstatus;
            $export->execute();
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
?>
```